# How Can I copy a File from ec2 to my local machine using scp

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a file called `output.txt` on a `Bitnami` instance. I'm trying to copy it to my local machine using the `scp` command on my local terminal window. But it will not copy. What am I doing wrong?

`scp -i /home/tom/Downloads/zoodigital.pem bitnami@52.191.41.160:/home/bitnami/output.txt`

Output:

`usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2`

Thanks

Comment: what error you get ?

Comment: Hi, all I got was the output above? Is this an error? The file didn't copy over.

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to specify the destination directory. To copy to the current directory, you can use

```sh
scp -i /home/tom/Downloads/zoodigital.pem \
  bitnami@52.191.41.160:/home/bitnami/output.txt ./
```

Answer (score 1):

Below command will work.

1. Go to directory (target) where you want to have contents.

   ```
   Eg : $ cd /home/tom/local-content
   ```
2. Execute scp command in this 'local-content' directory, in below format

   ```
   $ scp -i (path to pem file) (user)@(source machineip):/(source path) .

   (pay attention to final '.',  
    !! don't miss it)
   ```
3. In your case, scp command would be

   ```
   $ scp -i /home/tom/Downloads/zoodigital.pem bitnami@52.191.41.160:/home/bitnami/output.txt .
   ```

(where '.' - /home/tom/local-content directory)